# Why might @babel/preset-react automatic transform not succeed in conjunction with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

The environment is a Yarn monorepo where we also have a `babel.config.js` which defines the same. We're using React 18.1.x.

I have another config that's virtually identical and it works there, but it fails here. I've spent hours trying to find the difference - if there really is one.

**This is the runtime config:**

```js
[
  '@babel/preset-react',
  {
    runtime: 'automatic',
  },
],
```

**Our full Webpack config looks close to this pared down example:**

```js
module.exports = env => {
  return {
    resolve,
    entry: {
      entry: './src/entry.js',
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(?:js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                [
                  '@babel/preset-react',
                  {
                    runtime: 'automatic',
                  },
                ],
                '@babel/preset-typescript',
              ],
              plugins: [
                '@emotion',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types',
                ['@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx'],
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining', { loose: false }],
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions',
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
                '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                '@babel/plugin-transform-classes',
              ],
              babelrc: true,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'style.css',
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that we had `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx` under plugins.

If you're going to use automatic transform in `@babel/preset-react`, you have to remove `@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`.